# Prometheus scraping only some metrics

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring

In my cluster I have an nginx ingress, nodejs server and prometheus. Prometheus is scraping all metrics from nginx, no problem, but it seems that it's ommitting some metrics from my nodejs server.

```
# HELP nodejs_version_info Node.js version info.
# TYPE nodejs_version_info gauge
nodejs_version_info{version="v16.15.0",major="16",minor="15",patch="0"} 1
```

This metric is indeed scraped by prometheus because it has `nodejs_` in name. However, I also have some metrics which look like this:

```
# HELP http_request_duration_seconds duration histogram of http responses labeled with: status_code, method, path
# TYPE http_request_duration_seconds histogram
http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.003",status_code="200",method="GET",path="/"} 0
```

Metrics without nodejs in name do not appear in the dashboard, like so:

[image: Metrics]

I should mention that I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-prom-bundle for the response time metric. Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: Did you find a way around?

Comment: I played around with the configuration of the library and made sure that the metrics i wanted to use were prepended with `nodejs_`. You can see it here: [my github](https://github.com/malpa222/peer-chat/blob/bd304de82fe9c6e670b9ff32b60e9fc59457babc/frontend/server.js#L11)


I'm not sure if that worked, since it was for my school project quite some time ago :p I hope that it might help you.